# Build python file to Mac os app

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller, py2app

I'm Developing some python model which is build in Ubuntu. Now I want create executable file in Mac . Without building  in mac is it possible to do in UBUNTU.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to build anything it will work same on mac.
chmod +x filename
Or if you want app
https://py2app.readthedocs.io/en/latest/